# Unable to show tiff "parameters"

Tags: geotiff-tiff, qgis-2, visualisation

Why this raster (tiff) does not have any values?

Why I am unable to perform:

```
doubleclick -> onechannel pseudocolor -> clafify
```

Both rasters are downloaded from the same site: www.globalforestwatch.org
from their "data page" respectively.

**Working** (from picture below)
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/earthenginepartners-hansen/GFC2013/Hansen_GFC2013_lossyear_50N_130W.tif

**Not-working** (from picture below)
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/earthenginepartners-hansen/GFC2013/Hansen_GFC2013_lossyear_60N_140W.tif

What is the *difference* in these tiff's? **I am using Qgis 2.2 on Ubuntu.**

[image]

Comment: where are these tiles located ? Tiles with only water are provided for the sake of completeness but without data.

Comment: I am 100% sure that it is not water. (North-west coast of North America). Black box in right corner down is all land.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. The tile is OK.I could display it in ArcGIS (it just took a while). Have you tried to download the tile a second time ?

Comment: I tried to download it multiple times, from various computers, "HaveYouTriedToTurnItOffAndOnAgain" method...(Maybe some bug in QGis [2.2 version is quite new])..thank you for your help, I try ArcGis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a similar result when I load these tiffs into QGIS 2.2.0, with the 60N tif showing max and min values of 0.

Using the gdalinfo -stats option on these tifs suggests that both do have some values:

```
E:\TESTing>gdalinfo -stats Hansen_GFC2013_lossyear_60N_140W.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Hansen_GFC2013_lossyear_60N_140W.tif
       Hansen_GFC2013_lossyear_60N_140W.tif.aux.xml
Size is 36001, 36001
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-140.000138888888900,60.000138888888884)
Pixel Size = (0.000277777777778,-0.000277777777778)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-140.0001389,  60.0001389) (140d 0' 0.50"W, 60d 0' 0.50"N)
Lower Left  (-140.0001389,  49.9998611) (140d 0' 0.50"W, 49d59'59.50"N)
Upper Right (-129.9998611,  60.0001389) (129d59'59.50"W, 60d 0' 0.50"N)
Lower Right (-129.9998611,  49.9998611) (129d59'59.50"W, 49d59'59.50"N)
Center      (-135.0000000,  55.0000000) (135d 0' 0.00"W, 55d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=36001x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=12.000, Mean=0.010, StdDev=0.289
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=12
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0.010206085765138
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.2891400781453
```

and

```
E:\TESTing>gdalinfo -stats Hansen_GFC2013_lossyear_50N_130W.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Hansen_GFC2013_lossyear_50N_130W.tif
       Hansen_GFC2013_lossyear_50N_130W.tif.aux.xml
Size is 36001, 36001
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-130.000138888888900,50.000138888888884)
Pixel Size = (0.000277777777778,-0.000277777777778)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-130.0001389,  50.0001389) (130d 0' 0.50"W, 50d 0' 0.50"N)
Lower Left  (-130.0001389,  39.9998611) (130d 0' 0.50"W, 39d59'59.50"N)
Upper Right (-119.9998611,  50.0001389) (119d59'59.50"W, 50d 0' 0.50"N)
Lower Right (-119.9998611,  39.9998611) (119d59'59.50"W, 39d59'59.50"N)
Center      (-125.0000000,  45.0000000) (125d 0' 0.00"W, 45d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=36001x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=12.000, Mean=0.172, StdDev=1.156
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=12
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0.17243908812748
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=1.1560779557139
```

When I change the max value to a positive value and reclassify I get a comparable result.  I'm not sure if this is some issue with QGIS not reading the tiff metadata correctly, or whether there is some issue with the tif itself.

[image: comparison of tifs in QGIS 2.2.0]